# How to print a dictionary within a list in jinja2?

Tags: python, html, jinja2

So far I managed to print a list with key-value pairs

```
attendance list
{'Student ID': '15000000', 'Class attended': 1,'Total average score': 0.8}
```

code in html

```
 {% for key,value in attendance.items() %}
    <h1>{{key}}</h1>
    <h2>Value: {{value}}</h2>
 {% endfor %}
```

How do I print for this list?

```
allAttendance List
[{'Student ID': '15000000', 'Class attended': 1, 'Total average score': 0.8}, {'Student ID': '15000001', 'Class attended': 8, 'Total average score': 6.4}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would try something like this

```
 {% for student in allAttendance %}
    <h1>ID: {{student["Student ID"]}}</h1>
    <p>Attended: {{student["Class attended"]}}; Score: {{student["Total average score"]}}</p>
 {% endfor %}
```

You can add `{% for key,value in student.items() %}` if you wanted, but I would do it after the `h1` (though, you would then need to skip the ID key)

Note: If you had a list of some `Student` class, or database models, rather than dictionaries, you could use dot-notation to access attributes

Comment: Thank you for your fast response and your code is what I am looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a class to represent the data an HTML table for clean formatting:

```
class Data:
  def __init__(self, d):
     self.__dict__ = {a.lower().replace(' ', '_'):b for a, b in d.items()}

class Fulldata:
   def __init__(self, data):
      self.data = data
   def __iter__(self):
      for i in self.data:
          yield Data(i)


s = [{'Student ID': '15000000', 'Class attended': 1, 'Total average score': 0.8}, {'Student ID': '15000001', 'Class attended': 8, 'Total average score': 6.4}]
final_data = Fulldata(s)
```

---

Then, pass `final_data` to the templating object, and in your HTML, create the table:

```
<h1>Attendance List</h1>
<table>
 <tr>
   <th>Id</th>
   <th>Attendence</th> 
  <th>Average Score</th>
</tr>
{%for student in final_data%}
<tr>
  <td>{{student.student_id}}</td>
  <td>{{student.class_attended}}</td> 
  <td>{{student.total_average_score}}</td>
</tr>
{%endfor%}
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: I know that but what I am trying to acheive is that it will print out the key and value nicely. Sorry if my question wasnt clear enough will edit it.

Comment: @Han Apologies, I see what you are trying to do. Please see my recent edit.